# how to draw name infront of Mesh data ID UI

Tags: python, interface

```
layout.template_ID(obj, "data")
```

[image]

I assumed on could add `, text=""` inside the brackets but it seems not to work

```
layout.template_ID(obj, "data", text="Data Name")
```

[image]

I assume one could use row and lable commands drawing a text via label and the the template via the row command after it.

I am not sure if Blender does not allow what I try to do because also in the buttons menu there is no button text infron

[image]

So this is what I tried but the formatting result looks terrible.

```
    row = layout.row()
    row.label("Mesh Data")
    row.template_ID(obj, "data")
    row = layout.row()
    row.label("Object Name")
    row.template_ID(context.scene.objects, "active")
```

[image]

Alternatively I can also simply rebuild the main Blender UI elements and stretch them over the width of the panel like in the following image. This replicates also more a common visual look. But as you can see it is clean. The previous attempts were not vertically aligned along the left and right edge.
[image]

Comment: Maybe use an image editor to show what you'd like it to look like. It sounds like you want to use two columns the left column for names, the right column for the props.

Comment: or a row.split() see the UI cookbook.